# MULE ESB -> SOAP mapping - Easy Method don't work

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, mule

Hi all I'm new in Mule so please go easy on me. First of all I will show you example on SOAP UI:

Here is WSDL FILE: [wsdl file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16887656/test.wsdl)

[image: soap ui screeen]

Its pretty easy. I want to make exacly the same mule flow (no input data etc - payload set in code). The problem is that I simple even can't start. I read tutorial:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML-only+SOAP+Web+Service+Example

But still I can't do dataMappings like here. Any idea what I'm doing wrong my whole flow isn't big ... now its look like this:

```
<flow doc:name="PostRequest" name="PostRequest">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="getPostRequest" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="PostRequest" doc:name="SOAP"
            enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" clientClass="pl.execon.integration.axpppk.ws.client.XISGateway"
            port="XISGatewaySoap" />
     <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8889/Service/XISGateway.asmx" />
     <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String" />
</flow>
```

I want to use PostRequest ... Any advices ? Tutorials that can help ? Problem is that I need to make this envelope modification:

```
   <soap:Body>
      <m:PostRequest>
    <m:_requestCode>Test</m:_requestCode>
            <m:GetGasCustTable>
                         <m:XMLDocumentTime>2014-07-21T12:24:50</m:XMLDocumentTime>
                         <m:CustAccount>00043280</m:CustAccount>
           </m:GetGasCustTable>
      </m:PostRequest>
   </soap:Body>
```

And I Simply don't know how

Comment: Sorry but this tutorials show only how to create simple HELLO WORD without writing anything to payload problem is that I don't know how write this to SoapBody:    
`<soap:Body>
      <m:PostRequest>
    <m:_requestCode>Test</m:_requestCode>
            <m:GetGasCustTable>
                         <m:XMLDocumentTime>2014-07-21T12:24:50</m:XMLDocumentTime>
                         <m:CustAccount>00043280</m:CustAccount>
           </m:GetGasCustTable>
      </m:PostRequest>
   </soap:Body>`

Comment: If you want to consume an external webservice it need to be there  .. for example here you want to consume a webservice of http://localhost:8889/Service/XISGateway.asmx .. so this web service must exists in your localhost

Answer (score 0):

If want to use post and map a webservice just use pattern this is a working code for post method:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="webserviseName">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/localUWant" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8889/Service/XISGateway.asmx" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
</pattern:web-service-proxy>
```

As simple as that.

this is the documentation: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Mule+Configuration+Patterns